# Can I execute javascript on an element that is inside ui.selectable element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As the title says: can I execute javascript onclick on an dom element that is inside jQuery's ui.selectable dom element.

I hope it's clear where the problem is. The div inside my selectable div cannot be clicked because it inherits its parent elements selectable property.

I tried sth like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#myInnerDiv").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();   
    /*event.stopImmediatePropagation();*/
    alert("drek");
});

</script>

<div id="selectable">
   <div id="myInnerDiv">
       <!-- here is where I am clicking and Alert is Not showing up -->
   </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. I'm stuck here for three days now and would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Hmm... it may be that I'm not fully understanding the problem, but I've set up a jsFiddle project with your code and $.selectable, and it seems to work just as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/hRASm/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hRASm/15/ This looks more like what I am dealing with. I am not sure why it wont color up the bigger element just now? If it would it would match the situation I have at home.

Comment: If this modified demo (http://jsfiddle.net/william/hRASm/16/) is what you are after, I don't think you are using the selectables correctly... In other words, you should simply implement the effect yourself and discard the selectables all together.

Comment: Got it. This is what I was searching for http://jsfiddle.net/hRASm/44/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your javascript in a $(function() {}); call:

```
$(function() { 
$("#myInnerDiv").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    /*event.stopImmediatePropagation();*/
    alert("drek");
});
```

});

or you can put the script block after the HTML.